# C++ use file passed from command line in multiple functions

Tags: c++

I'm a real C++ noob but I have to do this assignment for school. The assignment concerns pipes which I've never heard of before.

So, first part of the assignment is to make a program that receives a file and reads how many characters, spaces, words and rows the file contains. This is what I have now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int GetCharCount(istream& i);
int GetWhitespaceCount(istream& i);
int GetWordCount(istream& i);
int GetRowCount(istream& i);

int main()
{
    cout << GetCharCount(cin) << endl;
    cout << GetWhitespaceCount(cin) << endl;
    cout << GetWordCount(cin) << endl;
    cout << GetRowCount(cin) << endl;

    return 1;
}

int GetCharCount(istream& i)
{
    char c;
    int count = 0;

    while(cin.get(c))
    {
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}


int GetWhitespaceCount(istream& i)
{
    char c;
    int count = 0;

    while(cin.get(c))
    {
        if(c == ' ' || c == '\t')
            count++;
    }

    return count;
}


int GetWordCount(istream& i)
{
    char c;
    int count = 0;
    bool wasWhitespace = true;

    while(cin.get(c))
    {
        if(isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)))
        {
            wasWhitespace = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if(wasWhitespace)
                count++;

            wasWhitespace = false;
        }
    }

    return count;
}


int GetRowCount(istream& i)
{
    string line;
    int count = 0;

    while(getline(cin, line))
        count++;

    return count;
}
```

When I run this on the command line like this: `cat inputfile.cpp | ./programReadFile` it correctly runs all the functions but only if other functions are commented. When I try to run the functions one after another, only the first one gives correct results and every function after that returns count of 0. It appears that the file can only be read correctly by one function and then it's deleted (or something).

Is this where the pipes come in use or what? I tried to store `cin` into a variable and then pass that variable to functions but I didn't get it to work.

Comment: a stream is ... well .. a stream ;) once you read all the file there is nothing left in the stream. You could reset the stream to the beginning of the file, however, as reading the file is the most expensive part in your code, you should read the file only once and get your statistics in one single loop

Comment: Did the assignment say you had to read the file with `cin`?  Probably better to read the file and hold it in some container...like a `vector` of `string` or something.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the other functions are not being called is because the first function extracts all the characters from the stream, leaving nothing for the rest of the functions. To solve this problem, create a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of characters to initially read all the contents of the file:

```
std::vector<char> allCharacters;

for (char x; std::cin >> x)
{
    allCharacters.push_back(x);
}
```

Next, modify all of your functions to accept a `vector`, not an `istream`, and iterate over all the characters in the container to check whatever condition you want. You could use an `std::string` in this case, but I personally feel that a `vector` makes more sense here and offers greater flexibility.

Comment: Your vector suggestion makes sense, but using ifstream instead of istream does not. Firstly, it is best to accept the more general istream because then your function can accept streams of any kind, rather than being tied to those from a file. Secondly, since his data is coming from stdin and *not* from a file, ifstream will not even work in this case. cin is an istream, not an ifstream.

Comment: @SeanBurton The input _is_ coming from a file. But you are right about the istream comment. So I have removed the last part of my answer.

Comment: The input may be originating from a file, but he is cat'ing the file then piping the stdout of cat to the stdin of his application, so as far as his application is concerned the data is coming from stdin and *not* from a file.

Comment: @SeanBurton true, but since the original origin _is_ from a file, why not just be able to run the executable and have the program itself take care of the file using `std::ifstream`?

Comment: That's an option, though in this case he said his assignment concerns pipes, so he probably has to use the pipe to stdin for this particular assignment. And this also allows data from stdin which isn't from a file, for example the generated output of another command, so can be more versatile. Most Linux commands are able to accept their input from stdin for this reason.

Comment: Ok, let's leave it at that